# Why does this code compile on Coderbyte but not locally?

Tags: java, compilation

I'm trying some programming challenges on coderbyte and programming in my own IDE as it's easier, but I don't know why the code it provides even compiles.

```
import java.util.*; 
import java.io.*;

class Main {  
  public static String MaximalSquare(String[] strArr) { 

    // code goes here   
    /* Note: In Java the return type of a function and the 
       parameter types being passed are defined, so this return 
       call must match the return type of the function.
       You are free to modify the return type. */

    return strArr[0];

  } 

  public static void main (String[] args) {  
    // keep this function call here     
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print(MaximalSquare(s.nextLine())); 
  }   

}
```

I get
Exception in thread "main" `java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem`:

> The method `MaximalSquare(String[])` in the type Main is not
>   applicable for the arguments (String)

when I try to compile it on my own computer, which is what I excpect as it's trying to pass a string to `MaximalSquare(String[] strArr)`, but I don't know why it compiles just fine on coderbyte

Comment: Does MaximalSquare have the same signature in coderbyte, are they using a varargs param instead of an explicit array?

Comment: It looks like Coderbyte does not actually compile the program, but instead calls the method directly passing in the parameter that is in the "Parameter Testing" box.   It is a bit of a shame that the first challenge on a site `Guaranteed to Make You a Better Coder` has a method that starts with an upper-case letter !

Comment: it looks more like the `Scanner` of thcoderbyte is tampered with for that challenge: `nextLine()` **there is** returning an array of strings (e.g. `[Ljava.lang.String;@74a14482`), if running for that given Challenge (others are *normal*) - this will **NOT** help improve your coding skills (at least you get used to very *strange* behavior and errors)

Comment: actually it is very *confusing*; on first challenge, if I change input from `8` to `8 4` I get lots of **compile** errors like: `')' expected  System.out.print(FirstFactorial(8 4));` - looks like the whole code is pre-compiled and Scanner calls are replaced by input value (code seems to be compiled, but not the *raw* input code)

Comment: @test - conclusion: use/trust your local IDE; not coderbyte

Comment: Ya, I'll just stick to my IDE. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Coderbyte has a bit of underlying code that parses it in a way that works for the function they set up for you to fill, while a normal IDE needs the programmer using it to convert/parse the information.

By the way, if you do want it to work on your IDE (and still don't know how to change it), convert the given string from scanner to a string array using `s.nextLine().split("\\s+")`